# Inequality exercise

Tags: inequality

This is my first post so I will try to be as brief and concise as possible.  I have been stuck with the following question for quite a while and feel as though I am missing a trick here and would appreciate a small nudge to help point me in the right direction.

I have the following question:

$\alpha(r)$ = $(1+r)^{p-1}$ + $(1-r)^{p-1}$

$\beta(r)$ = $\frac{(1+r)^{p-1}-(1-r)^{p-1}}{r^{p-1}}$

Where $ 0 \leq r\leq 1$ and $ 1 \lt p \lt 2$

I need to show that for any A,B $ \in \mathbb{R}$

We have the following satisfied:

$ \alpha(r)|A|^p + \beta(r)|B|^p \leq |A+B|^p + |A-B|^p$

Any help/pointers to aid me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.